# Data frame dictionary values to comma separated string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

How to convert a Pandas data frame dictionary to comma-separated string?

```
products = df.T.to_dict().values()
```

Example data `print(f"{product.items()}")`:

```
dict_items([('Category', 'My Category'), ('Title', 'My Title'), ('Catalouge Reference Number/SKU', 'abc123'), ('countryOfOrigin', 'usa'), ('generalDescription', '0.0'), ('Lead Time', '10')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select first row of DataFrame and join values in list comprehension:

```
L = [':'.join(x) for x in df.iloc[0].items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in `.to_csv()` function:

```
str_repr = df.to_csv(index=False)
```